# Objective C - Lost with retain cycles

Tags: ios, objective-c, retain-cycle

upon dismissing my VC, I noticed I am not releasing everything from memory. I'm very lost as to how I would go about finding my retain cycle. I am using an NSTimer and NSNotificationCenter, but I make sure to invalidate and removeObservers before exiting, and I made sure of using a weak delegate.

Where else could my retain cycles be occurring? In animation blocks?  Like this?

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:.1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                self.setListTableViewVertConst.constant = 0;
                self.setListTableViewHeightConst.constant = 264;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];
```

When using GCD I make sure to use weakSelf.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [weakSelf.remotePasswordTextField resignFirstResponder];
            });
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //Send the room code to be displayed on the respective view controllers. 
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toSetListRoomVC"]) {
        SetListRoomViewController *setListVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        setListVC.roomCode = self.roomCodeTextField.text;
    }

}
```

viewWIllApear

```
[super viewWillAppear:YES];


    self.socket = [[SocketKeeperSingleton sharedInstance]socket];
    self.socketID = [[SocketKeeperSingleton sharedInstance]socketID];

    NSString *roomCodeAsHost = [[SocketKeeperSingleton sharedInstance]hostRoomCode];
    /////////HOST/////////
    if ([[SocketKeeperSingleton sharedInstance]isHost]) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(receiveHostSongAddedNotification:)
                                                     name:kQueueAdd
                                                   object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(receiveUserJoinedNotification:)
                                                     name:kUserJoined
                                                   object:nil];

        NSLog(@"User is the host of this room");
        self.isHost = YES;
        [self viewForNoCurrentArtistAsHost];
        self.roomCodeLabel.text = roomCodeAsHost;

        if (!self.hostQueue) {
            self.hostQueue = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }
        if (!self.hostCurrentArtist) {
            self.hostCurrentArtist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        }

        if (!self.player) {
            self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc]init];
        }
        if (!self.timer) {
            self.timer = [[NSTimer alloc]init];
        }
    }

    ///////NOT HOST///////
    else {
        // Add a notifcation observer and postNotification name for updating the tracks.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(receiveQueueUpdatedNotification:)
                                                     name:kQueueUpdated
                                                   object:nil];

        //Add a notifcation observer and postNotification name for updating current artist.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(receiveCurrentArtistUpdateNotification:)
                                                     name:kCurrentArtistUpdate
                                                   object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(receiveOnDisconnectNotification:)
                                                     name:kOnDisconnect
                                                   object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(receiveHostDisconnectNotification:)
                                                     name:kHostDisconnect
                                                   object:nil];


        //Add some animations upon load up. Purple glow and tableview animation.
        double delay = .4;
        [self purpleGlowAnimationFromBottomWithDelay:&delay];
        [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

        //Set Current artist, if there is one.
        NSDictionary *currentArtist = [[SocketKeeperSingleton sharedInstance]currentArtist];
        [self setCurrentArtistFromCurrentArtist:currentArtist];


        //Set the current tracks, if there is one.
        NSArray *setListTracks = [[SocketKeeperSingleton sharedInstance]setListTracks];
        if (setListTracks) {
            self.tracks = setListTracks;
        }
    }
}
```

tableVIEWs

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
        if (self.isHost) {
            return [self.hostQueue count];
        }
        else return [self.tracks count];
    }
    else return [self.searchTracks count];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: does the previous viewcontroller (or something else) keep a (strong) reference to this viewcontroller at all? you would only really need to use weakSelf if you were keeping a reference to the block self was used in, in self (aka they reference each other, thus retain cycle) but i guess for async tasks it can be desireable for the thread to not have a strong reference to self, if self needs to deallocate even if the thread hasnt executed the code

Comment: You said in a comment that you are using segues to go between controllers. Are you using a segue to go back to a previous controller? If so, that's not a pop, unless you're using an unwind segue. Going back to a previous controller with anything other than an unwind creates a new instance, it doesn't go back to the one you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you are using the word "popOut" in some comments, so I'm going to assume that you are using a navigation controller.

If that is the case, your view controller is retained by the nav controller it's been embedded in and is not released. The nav controller needs to hold a reference to your VC (see UINavigationController.viewControllers)so that it can get back to it when you pop out the top/next VC in the hierarchy.

This is expected behavior.

Comment: Okay, but pushing and popping out seems to increase memory each time. So there is still a few leaks. I'll have to look at this in the morning.

Comment: Oh yes of course, spikes in memory indicate that something could indeed be leaking. To be honest, if the spike happens when "pushing" to the next VC, I would first check for allocations inside the new VC. Actually, the spike could be coming from allocating the new VC itself. Considered that possibility?

Answer (score 0):

In this code sample you are not using `__weak` for `self`

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:.1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                self.setListTableViewVertConst.constant = 0;
                self.setListTableViewHeightConst.constant = 264;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];
```

However, at a glance this does not seem to be creating a retain cycle. The code you posted doesn't seem to have any, so it's probably somewhere else. Are you sure you have retain cycles?

Anyway, try [instrumenting](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) you app. It might help.

Comment: When I popOut of the VC and return to it, all the data is retained. This is because of a retain cycle right?

Comment: No, not really. Actually, if there was a retain cycle holding your data you would have a *new*, clean, VC, while the old one would hang around in memory, lost forever in the app's realms. How are you instantiating your VC? Are you caching it? If so, it would explain that data persistency.

Comment: No I am not, is poping out of a VC suppose to make it new and clean? I want it to be new and clean when I pop out.

Comment: No, popping shouldn't do that, but instantiating it when pushing should. Again, how are you instantiating your VC? Plus, how do you initialise it?

Comment: I'm using storyboards and segues.

Comment: Are you preparing for the segue? How? I honestly don't see how to help without details on your implementation.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm now thinking maybe i dont have a retain cycle. But What I do see is that every time I push to the VC  and go back and forth while using it the memory goes up and up by 2-3MB

Comment: That's quite a lot, and if it doesn't get freed you probably have a leak indeed. Your segue preparation doesn't seem to be causing it either, so maybe try posting your `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidLoad`, or wherever you initialise your VC

Comment: keep in mind I am a noob, I posted my viewWillAppear. How should I initialize my VC?

Comment: It seems you are initialising it properly. Using singletons (those shared instances) could explain why the data is retained, but I'm guessing that the data which is being retained is the one on the table? Try posting your table's data source, as with the code you posted I still can't explain your issues

Comment: in my numberOfSections my only code was "return 1;" I did not account for seperate tableviews. But all tableviews should return 1

Comment: What exactly is being retained then?